# Difference in meaning of a paragraph when using plural vs. using singular nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns, plural-forms

Consider the following two paragraphs where one uses "the pen" and "pens" in different ways:

"**Reed pens** were used extensively until the development of **the quill pen** in 600AD.  **The quill pen** was made from the primary flight feathers of geese or more rarely swans".

vs.

"**The reed pen** was used extensively until the development of **quill pens** in 600AD. **Quill pens** were made from the primary flight feathers of geese or more rarely swans".

1. Is there any difference in meaning between the two paragraphs at all? If there is a difference in meaning, even very subtle, please elaborate.
2. If there is no difference in meaning, is there any rule or convention to stick to only one type of usage throughout an essay, i.e., if one already used "the quill pen" in the beginning, then one shouldn't use "quill pens" the rest of the essay?

Comment: I think there ***is*** a slight difference, which means your first version is more *likely* than the second. Using the article more strongly implies that ***the** quill pen* was a "specific" thing (that was "invented", so all actual instances of it would tend to be "the same", because they're "copied, made to a pattern"). Reed pens, on the other hand, were just an obvious easy way to make marks, that probably occurred to many different people at different times, using different patterns (sometimes from different types of reed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General statements "the+singular noun" or "plural noun"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322701/general-statements-thesingular-noun-or-plural-noun)

Comment: Per the excellent answer to that linked question, *When we use [ "the" + noun ] to refer to something in general, it means there's an understood general concept of that thing.* I'm sure that even though most of us have never used a quill pen, many of us will have seen them in movies and paintings and such, and they'd usually be easily recognised for what they are, since most of the barbs remain attached to the quill (the "stem"). But "reed pens" might just look more like some kind of stick anyway, and we're *much* less likely to see and/or recognise them for what they are.

Comment: Please bear in mind that "the quill pen" has the same meaning as: "quill pens". the quill pen there is not specific per se. It refers to quill pens as a whole. It is not "The quill pen on the table", which is specific.

Comment: @FumbleFingers does this mean that using "the reed pen" might not be accurate because we don't really have a general concept of what a reed pen looks like?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "accurate phrasing" in a context like this. No-one would seriously object to your second version above. I'm simply pointing out that I believe there's a ***slight*** difference, which means your first version is ***slightly*** more likely than the second. But I doubt most native Anglophones would ever become consciously aware of that if you just left them to think about the text of your question with no discussion or access to resources. It's a *very* fine point, but that "lack of a universally shared concept" is at the bottom of things, yes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. Also relating to this question, what about this third paragraph, whose only difference from the second one lies in the second sentence: "Reed pens were used extensively until the development of the quill pen in 600AD. A quill pen was (is) made from the primary flight feathers of geese or more rarely swans". Firstly, does using "a quill pen" here make any difference in meaning from the second one? Secondly, what should the tense be here?

Comment: It doesn't really make much difference whether you say *Quill pens are/were made from...* or *A quill pen is/was made from...* But a careful writer and/or a careful reader *might* just about make "meaningful" word choices and/or interpretations. Specifically, I'd be more likely to use the plural if the context inherently involved many quills - for example, talking about how everyone used them centuries ago, or a "craft shop" today that makes and sells them as "novelties". But if you were talking to someone who just wanted to try their hand at making one, singular might be a better choice...

Comment: ...and you could make a similar distinction between Past and Present tense depending on whether your context was quills as they existed and were used in the past, or as they still exist and might be used today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers regarding the tense used, is it right that even when the tense is past simple, the quill pens might still exist and be used today (but we just cannot tell)?

Comment: Most likely there are at least *some* quill pens in (occasional) use today, but the phrasing *Quill pens **were** made from...* does tend to imply that either they're no longer made at all, or they're made in a different way. If the product under consideration (X) was something that *definitely* doesn't / couldn't exist or be made that way today, you'd *have* to use Past tense. As in *Umbrella racks **were** made from elephants' legs.* But because it's at least *possible* to make and use quills today, you can use Present tense if you want. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways of talking about pens have different meanings, but in that context there's no functional difference between the two versions of that paragraph. If you read one to a native speaker and asked them to repeat it back, they'd be likely to replace "the reed pen" with "reed pens" and the other way around too.

As for the difference, generally speaking, in contexts like these, "*the X*" refers to *the general concept of something*, rather than an instance of the thing itself. In this particular context, the reed pen in an invention, so it refers to the concept of the reed pen as an invention, rather than any reed pen. "Reed pens" refers to the actual pens that were made and used.

So the start of the first paragraph means roughly, "***Actual reed pens** were used extensively...*", while the start of the second paragraph means roughly, "***The invention known as the reed pen** was used extensively...*". Since there's no difference between using a reed pen and using the invention known as a reed pen, the two paragraphs are understood exactly the same.

Comment: If "the reed pen" refers to the concept of the reed pen as an invention, then does the same thing apply to "the dog"? For instance, what is the difference between "the dog is man's best friend" and "dogs are man's best friend"? Clearly, we cannot refer to the dog as an invention.

Comment: @ASlowLearner I've added a bit to the start of my second paragraph. Does that fit better with "the dog"?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any difference in meaning between the two paragraphs at all?

No.

> If there is no difference in meaning, is there any rule or convention to stick to only one type of usage throughout an essay, i.e., if one already used "the quill pen" in the beginning, then one shouldn't use "quill pens" the rest of the essay?

It's question of style, not a rule.  Too much change will be confusing, but some change might make the passage less monotonous.  The writer should balance these considerations.  I would pick one form and stick to it, then, if I notice on rereading that the passage seems monotonous, I would consider changing the grammatical number as a way of relieving the monotony.